# Learning JavaScript for a total non-programmer

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive-javascript

I code CSS/XHTML like it should be my mother language, and I do write valid, semantic code following guidelines of accessibility and such.

But I want to learn Unobtrusive JavaScripting, but with a total non-programmer brain I need some motivation / tips / etc., like what's the best way to learn it, and how long does it take/did it take you before you could feel the power of knowledge? :)

PS: I do have an understanding on how JavaScript works and changes the DOM etc.. I think it's more about learning the syntax by head instead of having to look it up.

#### See also:

> [Suggestions for someone starting javascript programming.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284452/suggestions-for-someone-starting-javascript-programming)

Comment: I wonder if Js is a good beginner language or not. I think it's possibly too complicated to start with, because it's a hodgepodge of different concepts wrapped around in loose syntax and typing. Perhaps learn another language and then move onto Js? But then there might not be a reason to learn that language because it's not practical to you. Just thinking out loud.

Comment: Hmmm, after CSS/XHTML you might be too damaged to ever think logically again.  ;-)

Comment: JS is too complicated to start with? Hmm... Most of the confusion I see tends to come from programmers used to far more complex languages who approach JS expecting it to require the same sort of structure!

Comment: If I'll use JS for changing the DOM's CSS or XHTML, it shouldn't be too difficult. That way I guess I can take step by step away from the CSS/XHTML and learn more advanced code whenever my brain is ready for that, haha ;)

Comment: Good choice of a language. May I recommend Flash/ActionScript3? It has great documentation, is an extension or EMCAScript, like JavaScript, and Adobe releases a free, open-source, copy of their compiler under the name of "Flex SDK".AS2 was kind of dirty, but AS3 is clean, and MUCH faster than JavaScript (although JS is catching up with browsers like Chrome), because of it's compiled nature. The only trick is finding a nice (free) IDE. On Windows, I would recommend FlashDevelop, or on mac TextMate+AS3 Bundle (not free, but inexpensive), or XCode+Flex bindings (free, but not the best).

Comment: ^^^^^ Why can't I put line breaks in comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Motivation, sorry can't help there.

Syntax is learned by rote. The rules are simple, and reasonably consistent, so in truth syntax isn't that hard.

What you conflate with syntax are likely the other aspects like what properties are available on what objects, what functions to call, what does your framework provide. That, again, is basically rote memorization.

Many frameworks add a little bit of syntax through clever use of the JavaScript syntax, and you'll need to learn those as well.

But when it all comes down to it, the only way to learn this stuff is to use it.

You can't read about it, you have to do it.

Find an issue that you want to work on, a feature for your site or whatever, and attack that.

If you find a tutorial or whatever on line that does what you want, TYPE IN THE CODE, don't cut and paste it. As you type it in, question every symbol or character, try to understand why you're typing what you are typing.

Make an effort to change things, even if it's just variable names, because then you get a better idea of what things are being used for, and how they're referenced. It also lets you focus on a small part of the larger program.

If you're changing the "window1" variable to "myWindow", then at least you can look at the code as "blah blah blah window1 blah blah window1" without having to understand all of it.

Start small, don't worry about "doing it right", etc. so much as just being successful. If the way it's done doesn't bother you, then you're good. If you look at it and go "That's not quite right" because you learned something later after you started, then go back and clean it up.

At this stage, function is greater than form. Much of the form simply comes from experience.

Answer (score 4):

Just use it. Really, the more time you spend reading and writing the language, the more natural it becomes. Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or an equivalent console to test short ideas; take an existing web page and wire up events interactively from the command line, get used to the idea of writing behavioral code as a separate process from writing markup.

If you want a good book, i can recommend the excellent [jQuery in Action](http://www.manning.com/bibeault/) - yes, it's targeted at jQuery users, but the concepts apply regardless of your choice in libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you want to do. Are you a successful web designer who's considering getting into the development side? Forge ahead, but tread cautiously. JavaScript can be easy to start with, but it can get ugly very quickly. And it's very different from any server-side language (including Java). Some of your JavaScript skills will translate to other languages, (conditional and control-flow operators, for example). But some things are unique to JavaScript and will require some relearning if you move to another language.

Also, some things in JavaScript won't completely make sense unless you've done object-oriented development; even though JavaScript is "prototype-based" rather than strictly object-oriented, without the OO concepts to relate to, the prototyping system may be difficult to understand. The typing system also may not make much sense if you don't have a lot of experience with different typing systems (static vs. dynamic, explicit vs. implicit).

Use a good framework like jQuery or YUI, but be sure to understand what's going on behind the scenes. Shog9's suggestion to use FireBug is a good one, too. It will show you what's going on (without having to do a lot of alert() statements in your code).

Your HTML DOM and CSS experience will help some, but only in the sense of understanding what the JavaScript is trying to do. Having written HTML and CSS by hand won't help you learn to write JavaScript; HTML and CSS are document markup languages, not imperative programming languages.

So go for it, but don't expect it to be easy. You may make a lot of quick progress, only to find that you're not as far along as you think, and that things don't work the way the appear to. But with enough effort and research you'll probably get there.

Answer (score 1):

I think learning Javascript is a great idea if you are all ready doing HTML and CSS. Javascript is a cool, but quirky language.  Most people that use don't really know how to write good JS code. I highly recommend watching Douglas Crockford video, see http://video.yahoo.com/watch/111593

They will give the real scoop on Javascript.

Comment: Yaaay! China blocked me from watching that video but I'll get me a VPN account soon. Thanks anyways :D

Answer (score 1):

I've recommended [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748/) before (and can't recommend it highly enough), but if you're new to programming I suggest starting with [Head First JavaScript](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527747/).

[image: Head First JavaScript]
<sub>(source: [oreilly.com](http://oreilly.com/catalog/covers/9780596527747_cat.gif))</sub>

Comment: Thanks, think I've downloaded all the books mentioned here :) I'll get these printed up on a chinese university around here, cost like 1-2 USD to print up a whole book xD

Comment: "Javascript: The Good Parts" is such a great book, ++

Comment: @Frank Not for a newbie programmer, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got an abundance of great answers and resources already, but I'd like to chime in, too, since I've seen a couple of jQuery recommendations:

I love jQuery, too, and use it nearly daily. That said, for a beginner, I would recommend that you be comfortable with javascript proper **first** before diving into jQuery. Being comfortable with the syntax, variables, scope, and at least some DOM concepts will greatly improve your understanding of how to do what you want with jQuery. If you try to speed too quickly past the fundamentals, you'll definitely get stuck on some common misunderstanding that jQuery won't be able to help you with.

Answer (score 0):

http://codeavengers.com level 1 JavaScript is great for the complete beginner. I created the courses and have had lots of great feedback from beginners who have found my course a fun and effective way to learn JavaScript.